# Install NVIDIA Developer Drivers for GTX 630M on Fedora 16

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, fedora-16

I'm trying to install the developer drivers on my [**ASUS N53SM-ES72**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007BY57Y2) laptop, which has the Core i7-2670QM Sandy Bridge Processor and a GT 630M.

I've done a full installation of Fedora 16, with no dual-booting.  When I execute `lspci | grep -i VGA` I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation 
Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0de9 (rev a1)
```

Notice that even though an Nvidia card is listed, it cannot name it.

I've attempted to install the developer drivers with a mixture of the following guides:

- [**Fedora 16 nVidia Drivers Install Guide**](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/fedora-16-nvidia-drivers-install-guide-disable-nouveau-driver/)
- [**Installing Nvidia drivers on Fedora 16 – the wrong way**](http://geek.co.il/wp/2011/11/15/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-16-the-wrong-way)

I have ran the installer, but when I reboot, GNOME will not load up.

**How do I know if my card is even supported by the developer driver?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [optimus technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) in your laptop; that's means you got two graphics cards and you'll need to struggle a bit to let it work nicely in Fedora, using a project called [bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ).

First read Fedora own [wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee) for some preliminary informations; unfortunately it relies on free open source nouveau driver, as Fedora wont ship directly proprietary binary drivers.

So next step is going through [this guide](http://duxyng.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/finally-working-nvidia-optimus-on-fedora-16/), with which you will end with a working dual configuration using both nouveau and nvidia proprietary driver, shipped via [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) (no need to read this one, but can be useful if it's first time you use rpmfusion akmod drivers); be sure to also read comments, in particular the comment by Tomash Brechko, which is needed with kernels >= 3.3
Unfortunately again, some manual intervention is needed (as of writing) each time a new kernel/kernel driver is released.

Comment: Thanks. I actually decided on using that one guide in your answer a while back ago, and it works perfectly :)